# What does it mean by Outcomes favour $H_0$?

Tags: statistics

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKfiJ.png)

How would you know what outcomes favour $H_0$ or $H_1$?

Comment: The image does not define $H_0$ or $H_1$.

Comment: @almagest 
H0 : probability of heads is 0.5 versus
H1 : probability of heads is 0.7.

Comment: @JKnecht I know I'm sorry, I just haven't been to look at those at the moment due to exams, I will definitely take a look at them by today and up vote/accept them.

Comment: No problem. It was just a friendly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coin is tossed until the first head comes up and the total number of tosses is $X$.

This is a geometric random variable

$X \sim \text{geom}(p)$

With probability mass function

$P(X=x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$

$H_0: p=0.5$

$H_1: p=0.7$

With equal prior probabilities, the likelihood ratio:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{P(H_0|x)}{P(H_1|x)} &= \frac{P(x|H_0)}{P(x|H_1)}\frac{P(H_0)}{P(H_1)} \\
  &= \frac{(1-0.5)^{x-1}(0.5)}{(1-0.7)^{x-1}(0.7)}\frac{0.5}{0.5} \\
  &= \frac{0.5^x}{0.7 \cdot 0.3^{x-1}}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\frac{0.5^x}{0.7 \cdot 0.3^{x-1}} = 1 \Rightarrow x \approx 1.7 $$

And the ratio is greater than one for $x > 1.7$

A value of the ratio $> 1$ means that $H_0$ is more strongly supported by the data under consideration than $H_1$.

Hence if $X = 1$ it favors $H_1$, all other outcomes, $X \geq 2$, favours $H_0$.

Comment: Just a clarification, the last equation step, where you found x = 1.7, you basically just solved for x right?

And isn't the ratio also greater for x =2?
i.e. .25/.21 = 1.19

Comment: @Nash Yes i solved for $x$. The ratio is greater than $1$ for all $x > 1.7$ so it is also greater than $1$ for $x = 2$. And it is therefore every outcome of $X \geq 2$ favours $H_0$

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nash No problem, you're welcome.